# How can I set the best configurations for the project working with django, docker and mysql?

Tags: python, mysql, django, docker-compose, dockerfile

I was reading an article in [here](https://medium.com/@minghz42/docker-setup-for-django-on-mysql-1f063c9d16a0) which is about setting up project using docker, django and mysql together.

these are my files in project:

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.7
MAINTAINER masoud masoumi moghadam
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
ADD . /app

ADD requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt

RUN pip install --upgrade pip && pip install -r requirements.txt
```

**Docker-compose**

```
version: "3"

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app
    command: >
      sh -c "python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
    environment:
      - DB_HOST=localhost
      - DB_NAME=contact_list
      - DB_USER=root
      - DB_PASS=secretpassword
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=contact_list
      - MYSQL_USER=root
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=secretpassword
```

**requirements**

```
Django>=2.0,<3.0
djangorestframework<3.10.0
mysqlclient==1.3.13
django-mysql==2.2.0
```

and also this settings in my `setting.py`:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'HOST': os.environ.get('DB_HOST'),
        'NAME': os.environ.get('DB_NAME'),
        'USER': os.environ.get('DB_USER'),
        'PASSWORD': os.environ.get('DB_PASS')
        }
}
```

When I use `docker-compose build`  I face no problem and everything is just fine. Then I run `service mysql start`. I can assure that mysql service is in run and works because I have access to datasets.  The problem occurs when I do the migration using this command `docker-compose run app sh -c "python manage.py makemigrations core"` I get this error:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2002, 
"Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket 
'/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)")
```

When I change `localhost` to `127.0.0.1` I get this error:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: 
(2002, "Can't connect to MySQL 
server on '127.0.0.1' (115)")
```

I spent 20 hours looking for the best possible configuration for these technologies, But I still can't figure out anything. I also used python-alpine but I still could not find it useful for project because I had the same mysql dependencies problem when I was trying to do `docker build`. Does anybody have the same experience? I would appreciate if you could help me here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you use `localhost` as the host of `mysql` in `django`'s config.
But docker containers have their own IP, they are not localhost.

So first in your docker-compose file, name your containers :

```
db:
  image: mysql:5.7
  container_name: db
  ...
```

Then in your `django` settings, set your db HOST to your db container name : "db" :

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'HOST': 'db',
        'PORT' : 3306, # (?)
...
```

Also you are missing the db 'PORT' in django settings, I think that for Mysql it is 3306 (I've added it above).

Comment: Take a look at whole project:     https://github.com/masouduut94/Django_REST_API_Contact_List

Comment: Yes because you didn't change the HOST as I said, and as the tuto said...
Please don't try to go too fast, then you end up losing time.
Do everything I have written, one by one, slowly.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://testdriven.io/blog/dockerizing-django-with-postgres-gunicorn-and-nginx/) beautifully organized article, I found out this configurations will have no issues running on a server(changed mysql service to postgress service):

**Dockerfile**

```
# pull official base image
FROM python:3.8.0-alpine

# set work directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# install psycopg2 dependencies
RUN apk update \
    && apk add postgresql-dev gcc python3-dev musl-dev

# install dependencies
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
COPY requirements.txt /usr/src/app/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# copy entrypoint.sh
COPY entrypoint.sh /usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh

# copy project
COPY . /usr/src/app/

# run entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh"]
```

**Docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  web:
    build: app
    # container_name: web
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./app/:/usr/src/app/
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    env_file:
      - .env.dev
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    image: postgres:12.0-alpine
    # container_name: postgres
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=user
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=123456
      - POSTGRES_DB=contact_list
```

**requirements**

```
Django==2.2.6
gunicorn==19.9.0
djangorestframework>=3.9.2,<3.10.0
psycopg2-binary==2.8.3
```

**settings**

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': os.environ.get('SQL_ENGINE', "django.db.backends.sqlite3"),
    'NAME': os.environ.get("SQL_DB_NAME", os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "db.sqlite3")),
    'USER': os.environ.get("SQL_USER", "user"),
    'PASSWORD': os.environ.get("SQL_PASSWORD", "password"),
    'HOST': os.environ.get("SQL_HOST", "localhost"),
    'PORT': os.environ.get("SQL_PORT", "5432"),
}
```

}

I added a file named as `.env.dev` which is for better access to environment variables:

```
DEBUG=1
SECRET_KEY=123456
DJANGO_ALLOWED_HOSTS=localhost 127.0.0.1 [::1]
SQL_ENGINE=django.db.backends.postgresql
SQL_HOST=db
SQL_DB_NAME=contact_list
SQL_USER=user
SQL_PASSWORD=123456
SQL_PORT=5432
DATABASE=postgres
```

Answer (score -1):

first try to login to mysql with provided credentials

```
docker exec -it <CONTAINER_ID> /bin/sh
```

Inside the docker please login to mysql via command line

```
mysql -uroot -psecretpassword
```

Comment: Thanks for time and energy you spent on the question